# Using lag variable, by group

Tags: r, lag, missing-data

I have a `df` that looks like this and I need to run a code to produce `change`. `change` is defined as the first time to permanent positive `outcome` (`outcome` = 1).

The logic is as follows:

- Each `ID` has 5 `visits` with the value of the `outcome` at each `visit`
- The `change` variable can only be `1` if the outcome is `1` at `visit` x and thereafter
- For example, `id` 2 cannot have `change` = 1 at `time` 2 because the `outcome` reverts back to a negative result at `time` 3.
- An additional wrinkle includes the missing data. The potential outcome for `id` 3 at `visit` 2 could be 1 or 0. Since the value at this visit could be 1, then `change` should be 1.

My data with the desired output variable is

```
id visit outcome change
1   1     0       0
1   2     0       0
1   3     0       0 
1   4     1       1
1   5     1       0

2   1     0       0
2   2     1       0
2   3     0       0
2   4     1       1
2   5     1       0  

3   1     0       0
3   2     NA      1
3   3     1       1
3   4     1       0
3   5     1       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2,3), each = 5), visit = rep(1:5, 3), 
       outcome = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1,1,1))
df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(change = as.numeric(lead(outcome) == 1 & outcome == 1),
       change = ifelse(visit == 5, 0, change),
       change = ifelse(is.na(change), lead(change), change))
```